# C bytes - take off excess zeros (make it a char?)

Tags: c, int, byte

Hi I'm new to dealing with bytes and low level programming.  Currently, I have an int (32 bits)....so it looks something like this:

```
 0000000 10011011 00000000 00000000
```

I'm trying to output ONLY the 3rd set of 0's with the 1's (counting from the right).  So I'd be outputting a char value (?) How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can shift the bits right by 16 and then & it with 0x000000FF to clear all of the bits except the desired ones.

```
int i =  0b0000000100110110000000000000000;
char c = (i >> 16) & 0xFF;
printf("%c\n", c);
```

Comment: Glad to help. If you could mark this question as closed by accepting the answer that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = 1083899904;
    a = a >> 16;
    a = a % 256;
```

a now contains char value. you only have to cast it from here.

i was about to post this, but you were faster.